# How to solve the "http://xxx: E175002: can not read HTTP status line" error when using SVN client on Mac？

Tags: svn

When I use two different SVN clients for mac to connect with our SVN server, I always encoutner following errors when I try to checkout a repository:

http://xxxx: E175002: can not read HTTP status line
OPTIONS request failed on 'xxxx'

While I use the webbrowser to open the repository directly, it works well.

The clients are Syncro SVN client for Mac 9.0 and SMartSVN version 8.

My Mac is OS X 10.10.

Is there anyone who has the same experience and has solved it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any VPN clients installed recently? Even we have faced the same issue by installing CISCO VPN client. Even Cisco VPN is not running, facing the same issue.

If that is the case, then disable 'Web Security' option in that VPN client.

sudo /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/websecurity_uninstall.sh